# Como comprobar en un if el estado de un enum

Tags: java, lista, poo, enum

Saludos como puedo comprobar el estado del Empleado a través del enum mi condicional no reconoce el Estado.Activo quiero poder descontar sólo si el estado es Activo quizas mi forma de comprobarlo no sea la correcta alguna idea sugerencia Gracias

```java
public class Empleado{
    
    private String nombre;
    
    private char sexo;
    
    private double sueldo;
    
    private Estado estado;
    
    public Empleado(String nombre, char sexo, double sueldo){
    
        this.nombre=nombre;
    
        this.sexo=sexo;
    
        this.sueldo=sueldo;
    
        this.estado=estado.ACTIVO;
    
    }
    
    public Empleado(String nombre, char sexo, double sueldo, Estado estado){
    
        this.nombre=nombre;
    
        this.sexo=sexo;
    
        this.sueldo=sueldo;
    
        this.estado=estado;
    
    }

    public Estado getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }
}


public enum Estado{
    ACTIVO,
    INACTIVO,
    BAJA,
    VAVAVIONES;

} 


    public static void descontarPorcentaje(){
        
        System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del empleado");
    
        String nombre=scan.nextLine();
    
        for(int i=0;i<empleados.size();i++{
            Empleado em=empleados.get(i);
            Estado e=em.getEstado().ACTIVO;
            if(empleados.get(i).equals(e){
                em= empleados.get(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pon el código de tu clase Empleado.

Comment: He puesto la clase Empleado no tiene setters  sólo getEstado().

Answer (score 2):

Su ciclo es un poco desordenado y algunos conceptos no son del todo correctos.

Debe utilizar las enumeraciones **como constantes estáticas**, no necesita instanciarlas, solo utilícelas como una constante estática. Otra cosa (no es cierto para todos los casos), pero puede comparar enumeraciones con `==`, porque no son cadenas en su caso, son enumeraciones y no tienen un valor de cadena. En realidad, es un poco más seguro ya que no necesita tratar nulo, pero solo si su enumeración es simple.

De todos modos, el problema es que estás haciendo muchas instancias y conversiones, y no usas la enumeración, todas esas instancias están creando diferentes objetos.

Verifique este código a continuación, especialmente el uso de la enumeración:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Empleado[] empleados = {
                new Empleado("aaaa", 'V', 100d),
                new Empleado("bbbb", 'M', 100d, Estado.BAJA),
                new Empleado("cccc", 'M', 100d, Estado.INACTIVO),
                new Empleado("dddd", 'V', 100d, Estado.VAVAVIONES),
                new Empleado("eeee", 'M', 100d)
        };
        
        for (int i = 0 ; i < empleados.length ; i++) {
            Empleado em = empleados[i];
            if (em.getEstado().equals(Estado.ACTIVO)) {
                System.out.println(em.getNombre() + " esta " + Estado.ACTIVO);
            }
        }
        
    }

}

enum Estado {
    ACTIVO, INACTIVO, BAJA, VAVAVIONES;
}

class Empleado {

    private String nombre;
    private char sexo;
    private double sueldo;
    private Estado estado;

    public Empleado(String nombre, char sexo, double sueldo) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.sueldo = sueldo;
        this.estado = Estado.ACTIVO;
    }

    public Empleado(String nombre, char sexo, double sueldo, Estado estado) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.sueldo = sueldo;
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public char getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }
    public void setSexo(char sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }
    public double getSueldo() {
        return sueldo;
    }
    public void setSueldo(double sueldo) {
        this.sueldo = sueldo;
    }
    public Estado getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }
    public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }
}
```

la salida es

```
aaaa esta ACTIVO
eeee esta ACTIVO
```

Comment: Gracias la forma correcta es comparar em.getEstado() == Estado.ACTIVO y evitar el equals en este caso.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes errores manejando el enum `Estado`:

En la clase Empleado, estado por defecto es null, por lo que

```
this.estado=estado.ACTIVO;
```

es un error (¿una errata?) y debería ser

```
this.estado = Estado.ACTIVO; //con mayúscula haciendo referencia a la clase enum
```

Y a la hora de iterar, el bucle debería ser algo como:

```
        for (Empleado em: empleados) {
            if (em.getEstado() == Estado.ACTIVO){
               // hacer algo con em
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gracias me parece que al ser clase estática  había que poner Estado.ACTIVO